# Tika messed up the structure of my document, how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-tika, data-munging

After extract the textual content from some PDF files I noted that tika misaligned my document's text, for example my original PDF doc looks like this:

```
Animal name:                            Cat
Food stock:                             Avalaible
type:                                   male
```

After using tika:

```
cat
Animal name:                            
Available
Food stock:                             
male
type:
```

How can I tell tika to preserve the white spaces?.

Comment: Did you try following https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#PDF_Text_Problems ?

Comment: Yes, however I do not understood how to fix the dcoument @Gagravarr